# Android can use like apple push-notification with php?

Tags: php, android, push-notification

i use php to post to apple ..

> $message = $error_msg;
>
> ```
>   $deviceToken = $dtoken;
>   $badge = 1;
>   $sound = 'received3.caf';
>     $body = array();
>     $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
>     if ($badge)
>             $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
>     if ($sound)
>             $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;
>     $ctx = stream_context_create();
>     stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/home/administrator/applecert/apns-dev.pem');
>     $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
>     error_reporting(E_ALL);
>     if (!$fp) {
>             print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
>             return;
>             } else {
>            print "Connection OK\n";
>         }
>     $payload = json_encode($body);
>     $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
>     print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";
>     fwrite($fp, $msg);
>     fclose($fp);
> ```

and andriod have similar way to post with php?

thanks ,all

Comment: Got same problem here ,no ideas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the C2DM service google offers :

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/android/c2dm/

Answer (score 0):

This code is well tested.

Note : You need to remember 3 points to check.

1. Passphrase : confirm with IOS developer.
2. .PEM : Please verify with your IOS develoepr created '.PEM' file is for sandbox or live server.
3. PORT 2195 : Need to verify whether this port has opened or not on your server.

If you have done these 3 steps, Now you can send push notification with below code with few configuration changes.

```
 function pushNotification($deviceToken, $msg, $sounds, $type) {

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '');
        // Put your private key's passphrase here: 
        $passphrase = ;
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
                'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert'  => $msg,
            'sound'  => $sounds,
            'badge'  => 1,
            'type'   => $type,
        );
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        // print_r($result);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```